# How to extract labels values from a metric with regex in Grafana?

Tags: regex, variables, grafana

In Grafana I have a Variable with a Query:

Type: Query

Data Source: Prometheus

Refresh: On Dashboard Load

Query: node_uname_info{server=~"$server"}

Result: node_uname_info{clusterdb1="CLUSTER1",clusterdb2="CLUSTER2",domainname="(none)",machine="x86_64",nodename="MYSERVER",release="3.8.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64",server="MYSERVER",sysname="Linux"}

How can I extract CLUSTER1 and CLUSTER2?

I tried with:
.*clusterdb.="([^"]+)".*clusterdb.="([^"]+)".*

And it works in https://regex101.com/ but not in Grafana.

Any help will be much appreciate it!

Comment: Is clusterdb1 and clusterdb2 labels fixed? Or there are more lables clusterdb3, 4?

Comment: They are fixed. I plan to add more labels though. 3,4,5.. Thanks.

Comment: May I know why you need so many labels to identify the clustedb. Having one label clusterdb and assigning values like cluster1, cluster2, cluster3 should help right? Having so many different labels will defeat the purpose of labels

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels

Comment: Im templating variables hence I need 2 separated values CLUSTER1 and CLUSTER2 I can use to choose in my dashboard.

Adding a label clusterdb: CLUSTER1,CLUSTER2 in my prometheus.yml

and

Querying it from grafana with:

label_values(node_uname_info{server=~"$server"}, clusterdb)

It gives me 1 value called:

CLUSTER1,CLUSTER2

I need 2 separate values I can then select from my dashboard:

CLUSTER1 CLUSTER2

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus data source plugin provides the following functions you can use in the Query input field.

> label_values(label)   Returns a list of label values for the label in
> every metric.
>
> label_values(metric, label)   Returns a list of label values for the
> label in the specified metric.

Refer the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable)